# How to Lerp a rotation the shortest path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a tank, which is made of a base and turret on top, both separate but under a parent object. To shoot, the turret will rotate to the shooting direction, then lerp back towards the tanks base rotation. 
I want to rotate the turret in the shortest possible direction. So if the base is at 0 degrees and the turret is at 270, I change the 270 to -90 and it will lerp from -90 to 0, however if the base is at 180 and the turret is at 270, it needs to lerp from 270 to 180, not from -90.

This is my current code.

```
    void StackFunction()
    {
        float turretRotation;
        float bodyRotation; 

        turretRotation = this.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        bodyRotation = playerBody.transform.eulerAngles.y; 

        if (turretRotation > 180)
        {
            turretRotation -= 360; 
        }

        float targetRotation = Mathf.Lerp(turretRotation, bodyRotation, lerpRate);

        this.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.x, targetRotation, this.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
```

This is my current code. It works fine when the body is facing 0, however it all inverts when the body swaps to 180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpolate rotations with [Quaternion.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) or even better [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html).

```
Quaternion from = this.transform.rotation;
Quaternion to = playerBody.transform.rotation;

void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(from, to, lerpRate);
}
```

Comment: Why is `Slerp` better? And why don't you use it in the example if it is better? ;)

Comment: well as we can see "better" depends on the use case ;) If you **want** easing at start and end you would probably prefer `Lerp` over `Slerp`

Comment: @derHugo Yep, though easing will be inconsistent. For example, if your from and to vectors are 180 degrees apart, you will only have one frame in between. For rotational easing I would prefer to use `Slerp` with an easing function e.g. `Mathf.SmoothStep` on the lerp value.